# When the event worldCreated is triggered?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It sounds like a self answering question, but what I really would like to understand is *when* a World is created, because currently my callback connected to this event is never called.

Bit of context:

I'm runninging a ModelPlugin. The model has a camera which is inside the meshes, so the model visual itself blocks the camera view. I already managed to set the visibility so the camera do not see the object. However, I'm only able to do it from the callback that is called when the event `worldUpdateBegin` is triggered.

I though I could use `worldCreated` or `createdEntity`, but they are never called.

The visuals are not "ready" neither on my Init() or Load() methods. So I would like to understand better the Event signals so I can choose one where:

1. Visual Entities are available for manipulation
2. It is not called periodically.

I'd appreciate if someone could give me a hint.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21815/when-the-event-worldcreated-is-triggered?/) by [rasecg3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7335/rasecg3/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `worldCreated` event is triggered before `ModelPlugin`s are loaded, so I wouldn't expect such plugins to ever hear the event. That is meant to be used by `SystemPlugin`s.

If you're dealing with `Visual`s, I'd suggest you use a `VisualPlugin` instead of a `ModelPlugin`. That plugin's `Load` method should be called when the visual is ready.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1